# git/ssh config: how to manage multiple usernames

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have 2 bitbucket accounts: one personal and one owned by the compagny I'm working for.

I set ssh config file and put the ssh public key's for my personal account.

```
Host perso-bitbucket
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/perso-key
```

Everything is working fine.

```
$myUsername: ssh -T perso-bitbucket 
logged in as myUsername.
```

Now, I add a second ssh-key:

```
Host pro-bitbucket
  User git
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pro-key
```

and add the public key to my bitbucket account proUsername.

The question is how can I say to ssh/git which username to use?

```
$myUsername: ssh -T pro-bitbucket 
logged in as myUsername.
```

Here, it should use proUsername. It does not work even if I set git's user as proUsername :

```
git config --global user.name proUsername
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you wish to access your personal bitbucket account with your personal key and your company's bitbucket account with a different key? If yes then maybe the answer I wrote to a similar question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/43692897/2928051

Comment: Setting git user name with `git config --global user.name username` only specifies the name which will be added to git commit objects. This can be different from your bitbucket username. When you test your ssh connection with `ssh -T perso-bitbucket`, ssh is implicitly using the username `git` which is defined in your ssh config. If the key is valid, bitbucket will respond with the bitbucket username the key was mapped to.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and finally wrote a bash script handling that. You can find it here [recursive-gitconfig](https://github.com/arount/recursive-gitconfig).

The idea is to force `git` command to use as specific `.gitconfig` file depending of `cwd`.

So the exposes a bash `git` function seaking for a `.gitconfig` file in parents directories and use first match as git config file.

---

Here is how I use it:

file `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    email = arnout@spam.bacon
    name = Arount
[core]
    editor = vim
[alias]
    lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
    lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
    ...
```

So here is my global config, I'm *Arount* and I have my editor & aliases setted.

file `~/Work/.gitconfig`:

```
[include]
    path = /home/me/.gitconfig

[user]
    email = the-coporate-me@my-super-company.lol
    name  = My Real Me
```

So everywhere I use `git` I'm Arount, but in `~/Work/` I'm the corporate me. You can make several layers (`Work/compagny1`, `Work/campgny2`), recursion, etc ..

You can update and override *every* `gitconfig` config key.

---

Here is the code, but I recommends to use github link upper

```
#!/bin/bash
# Look for closest .gitconfig file in parent directories
# This file will be used as main .gitconfig file.
function __recursive_gitconfig_git {
    gitconfig_file=$(__recursive_gitconfig_closest)
    if [ "$gitconfig_file" != '' ]; then
        home="$(dirname $gitconfig_file)/"
        HOME=$home /usr/bin/git "$@"
    else
        /usr/bin/git "$@"
    fi
}

# Look for closest .gitconfig file in parents directories
function __recursive_gitconfig_closest {
    slashes=${PWD//[^\/]/}
    directory="$PWD"
    for (( n=${#slashes}; n>0; --n ))
    do
        test -e "$directory/.gitconfig" && echo "$directory/.gitconfig" && return 
        directory="$directory/.."
    done
}


alias git='__recursive_gitconfig_git'
```

I recommend to copy this file in something like `~/.recursive-gitconfig.sh` and add `source ~/.recursive-gitconfig.sh` within the firsts lines of your `.bashrc`.