# How do I generate a new ssh-key for my new gitlab account?

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have two Gitlab accounts. On my **old account** I added an **ssh-key** that is located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on my computer.

Now I want to add another **ssh-key** for my new Gitlab account. How do I do this without having the ssh-keys conflict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client)

Comment: @phd No, my question is different, my question relevant on multiple gitlab account corresponding multiple ssh-keys, and I had already read that qeustion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple SSH Keys on the same device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43662029/608639)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would recommend a second key, for now without passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com" -P "" -q -f ~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

That will create (without any prompt) `~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa` (private key) and `~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa.pub` (public key)

You need to [register that second `gitlab_rsa.pub` public key to your second GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair).

> Navigate to the 'SSH Keys' tab in your 'Profile Settings'. Paste your key in the 'Key' section and give it a relevant 'Title'.

Then add a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host gitlab_rsa
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /home/<you>/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

Finally, you can clone any GitLab repo as your second identity with:

```
git clone gitlab_rsa:<yourSecondAccount>/<yourRepo.git>
```

That will be replaced automatically with `git@gitlab.com:<yourSecondACcount>/<yourRepo.git>` and will use your second key.

Comment: Do you mistake "/Users" instead of "/home" ?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari yes, simple typo, but the general idea in this answer still stands.

Comment: I have problem with this following structure yet: when I git clone,I will encountered this error: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Is your second Gitlab public key registered in your second Gitlab account?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Is your URL `gitlab_rsa:<yourSecondAccount>/<yourRepo.git>`? With the right Gitlab username and repo name?

Comment: can I directed write "replaced automatically" commands ("git clone git@gitlab.com:<yourSecondACcount>/<yourRepo.git>") instead of "git clone gitlab_rsa:<yourSecondAccount>/<yourRepo.git>"?

Comment: Yes these are same with gitlab, but I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari if you are using the `git@gitlab.com:<yourSecondAccount>/<yourRepo.git>"`, the default id_rsa private key will be used. Only `gitlab_rsa:<yourSecondAccount>/<yourRepo.git>` would force SSH to use the right private key. Internally, SSH will replace that URL with the right one.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Can you test the authentication with `ssh -Tv gitlab_rsa`? You should see a welcome message?

Comment: That result:
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/benyamin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab_rsa: Name or service not known

Comment: @BenyaminJafari That is because your `~/.ssh/config` does not have an entry `Host gitlab_rsa`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Well done! From there, you should be able to clone your repo

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
worked it.  but when I use mySecondAccount after gitlab_rsa in git clone commad, encountered error, but I use project owner account instead, and worked: `git clone gitlab_rsa:<ownerProjectAccount>/<Repo.git>`

Answer (score 3):

Generate a new key pair with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

It will ask you to enter a name for the key file:

```
 Enter a file in which to save the key (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]
```

Choose something different such as /Users/you/.ssh/gitlab_rsa

Then when you need it add this key to your ssh-agent with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

If you want a permanent access you can edit your `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host gitlab_rsa
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /home/<you>/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

Refer to this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) for further details.

Comment: I think you should use "gitlab_rsa" instead of "second" corresponding your answer.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari That was just copied from my answer.

Comment: yes that's write, but I attempt to repair it for my better understanding

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the file `~/.ssh/config` to define which key should use for every domain.

Create that file with nano and paste your configuration:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

And add:

```
Host your-gitlab.com
    HostName your-gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your-gitlab-privkey
```

Comment: what do you mean "your-gitlab.com" ?

Comment: `your-gitlab.com` should be your GitLab url, where you are going to connect. Like if I want to link that key to github.com -> `Host github.com` and also `HostName github.com`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari That is what I explain in my answer (written before this duplicate one): what you put in your ssh/config is a key: you will use that key in your SSH URL.

Comment: @VonC , no need to put  '(written before this duplicate one)'. Just comment on your own entry.

Answer (score 3):

Generate SSH please follow below steps.

Open Git Bash on you machine

[image]

Enter the below command to genarate

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourmail@example.com"

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa):Press enter
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): Type a passphrase
Enter same passphrase again: Type passphrase again

Once enter the confirm passphrase, will get confirmation message.

[image]

go to the gitpair.pub file location and right click open with notepad.
copy the code and past the in the below text box, your email will pick automatically in the title box.
then click add key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just apply two commands :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy ssh key and paste on browser