# How can I have two account in gitlab which they participates in a project on a PC (two ssh_key)?

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have **two account in gitlab**,
I want these accounts join on **a project** in gitlab as separate in my PC (as two ssh-key which added in gitlab profiles)
How do I switch between these account in my PC without any conflict or some things like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate new ssh-key for my new gitlab account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248144/how-do-i-generate-new-ssh-key-for-my-new-gitlab-account)

Comment: @phd In this question I hope to know how can I switch between these own accounts on a project in gitlab (single gitlab project, not two gitlab)!

Comment: But the answer is the same. You configure ssh. There is no magic that would switch keys for you.

Comment: So, you have 2 ssh keys and added 1 of them to each profile, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a Linux terminal, you can create an [ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) session, then add, using [ssh-add](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) only the key of the account you want to use. For instance, if you want to use **account 1**:

```
eval `ssh-agent` # creates new ssh-agent session
ssh-add ~/.ssh/account1_rsa # add identity for account 1
```

ssh-agent session is valid for your terminal session, so you can open a second terminal and do the same for *account 2*.

I'm almost sure you can do the same in Windows using git's terminal.

[Here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeww) a longer tutorial using ssh-agent and ssh-add.

Comment: can you more explain?

Comment: Added more details to the answer